# Bash nested quotes and eval

Tags: bash, nested, eval, quotes

I'm having difficulty nested quotes within a bash script

```
argv="su -c '$RVM_PATH wrapper $config_rvm \'$PASSENGER_RVM_BIN $command $options\'' web"
eval $argv
```

The above got me

```
eval: line 162: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
eval: line 163: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
argv="su -c \"$RVM_PATH wrapper $config_rvm \\\"$PASSENGER_RVM_BIN $command $options\\\"\" web"
```

Answer (score 9):

That's because `\'` doesn't have any special meaning within a single-quoted string; it means simply "backslash, followed by end-of-string".

One option is to use `$'...'` instead of `'...`'; that will let you use backslash-escapes. It would look like this:

```
argv="su -c $'$RVM_PATH wrapper $config_rvm \'$PASSENGER_RVM_BIN $command $options\'' web"
```

The downside is that if there's any chance that `$RVM_PATH`, `$config_rvm`, or any of the other variables could include a backslash, then it too could be interpreted as introducing a backslash-escape.

Answer (score 8):

[Use an array instead.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=(echo "foo bar")
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that link you provided discusses your suggested use of bash arrays.

Comment: @TomHale: My answer had a syntax bug.

Answer (score 0):

## Generic solution for `eval` with correctly quoted arguments

The following function uses the shell's own quoting mechanism to that I don't have to worry about how to correctly quote things:

```
function token_quote {
  local quoted=()
  for token; do
    quoted+=( "$(printf '%q' "$token")" )
  done
  printf '%s\n' "${quoted[*]}"
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
$ token_quote token 'single token' token
token single\ token token
```

Above, note the `single token`'s space is quoted as `\`.

```
$ set $(token_quote token 'single token' token)
$ eval printf '%s\\n' "$@"
token
single token
token
$
```

This shows that the tokens are indeed kept separate.

---

Given some untrusted user input:

```
% input="Trying to hack you; date"
```

Construct a command to eval:

```
% cmd=(echo "User gave:" "$input")
```

Eval it, with **seemingly** correct quoting:

```
% eval "$(echo "${cmd[@]}")"
User gave: Trying to hack you
Thu Sep 27 20:41:31 +07 2018
```

Note you were hacked. `date` was executed rather than being printed literally.

Instead with `token_quote()`:

```
% eval "$(token_quote "${cmd[@]}")"
User gave: Trying to hack you; date
%
```

`eval` isn't evil - it's just misunderstood :)